# stat_summary2d missing an already supplied aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code works as it should:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100000, 0, 5), y = rnorm(100000, 0, 5), z = rnorm(100000, 42, 42))

hexHist = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, z = z)) + 
    stat_binhex(bins = 10) +
    stat_summary_hex(aes(label=..value..), bins = 10,
                     fun = function(z) {
                         (round(sum(z)/length(z), 0))
                     },
                     geom = "text")
```

But, when I change `stat_binhex` to `stat_bin2d` and `stat_summary_hex` to `stat_summary_2d`, I get the following error:

> `geom_text` requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y

Explicitly adding the arguments `x = dat$x` and `y = dat$y` to `aes` doesn't change anything. Why isn't `stat_summary_hex` seeing the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to this [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/6lx_mYJVf3w) there is no out-of-the box solution to your question, since stat_bin2d is optimised to work with 
geom_rect - it returns xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax aesthetics, not the x 
and y aesthetics that geom_text needs.

However a workaround can be applied, I used `data.table` package for it.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100000, 0, 5), y = rnorm(100000, 0, 5), z = rnorm(100000, 42, 42))

hexHist = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, z = z)) + 
  stat_bin2d(bins = 10)

dat = data.table(dat)
newdat <- data.table(ggplot_build(hexHist)$data[[1]])
newdat[,xmean := (xmin + xmax)/2]
newdat[,ymean := (ymin + ymax)/2]
newdat[,z:=round(sum(dat[x>xmin & x<xmax & y > ymin & y<ymax]$z)/length(dat[x>xmin & x<xmax & y > ymin & y<ymax]$z)) ,by=c('xmean','ymean')]
hexHist + geom_text(data=newdat, aes(xmean, ymean, label=z), col="white")
```

Comment: Using `setDT()` instead of `data.table()` is more performant.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's *supposed* to work, but there's currently an issue w/ `ggplot_build` where the bin centers aren't the *actual* bin centers. It's the same problem as [this](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1383). For some reason, it works perfectly w/ 15 bins, but no more or less. (This is why I ended up using `stat_summary` instead)